# Data Visualisation API

Tags: api, testing, data-visualization, genetic-algorithm

I am writing a basic genetic algorithm(string evolver) implementation in C . 
It takes a few inputs like reference string and population size and returns generations required to evolve .

Can someone suggest an API /framework that would help me run this code again and again , with several inputs , collect the data and create specific visualisations and charts based on the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to use whatever you have on your hands. It sounds like Matlab is an appropriate tool for plotting. What you need is then an interface between Matlab and C which can either be based on Mex or Matlab Engine. You could even simply call your application via command line and collect the results from a file, which might be the slowest approach.

Comment: matlab crossed my mind too , but i was looking at more of an API solution , ie , pass the framwork the function , let it run and give the final output. if that is possible that is.

Comment: you can call matlab from C code using, again, both Mex and Matlab Engine!